# Dynamic Select Statement in C# to MySQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql, select

I have quite a number of questions lately about SQL statements in MySQL, but I none have fit my purpose.

I have a class which is where my SQL statements will be saved so that I could use them as methods to keep my code neat. I have already done the Insert, Update, Delete, and Count statements, but I can't seem to find a solution for the SELECT statement

Here are the codes for the other statements:

```
public void Insert(string query)
    {
        if (OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mycon);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            CloseConnnection();
        }
    }

    public void Update(string query)
    {
        if (OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Connection = mycon;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            CloseConnnection();
        }
    }

    public void Delete(string query)
    {
        if (OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mycon);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            CloseConnnection();
        }
    }

    public int Count(string query)
    {
        int count = 0;

        if (OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mycon);

            count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar() + "");

            CloseConnnection();

            return count;
        }

        else
        {
            return count;
        }
    }
```

I am thinking of a SELECT method that would look something like this:

```
    public string[] Select(string query, int colnum)
    {
        if (OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mycon);
            MySqlDataReader dr = new MySqlDataReader();
            string[] info = new string[colnum];
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= colnum; i++)
                {
                  info[i] = (dr[colnum].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this line is quite fictional `info[i] = (dr[colnum].ToString());`
 since I know It will not function the way I want it to. I am looking for something with a similar logic or something like that that would let me take advantage of the SELECT statements by using methods..

Comment: Aren't you trying to re-invent ORMs? And what's wrong with using ADO.NET classes like datatables if you are going to read all values from the database anyway? You spend the same amount of time only to loose type safety

Comment: PS: Your Insert etc statements are exactly the same and do not ensure that an Insert or Update statement is actually executed. Perhaps you should get comfortable with the ADO.NET way of doing things first.

Comment: May I ask for a link to a good resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use Nhibernate (http://nhforge.org/). Read http://geekswithblogs.net/pariam/archive/2006/07/26/86352.aspx for a tutorial to use nhibernate with mysql

**EDIT:**
With your code, I am not sure about how concurrency can be handled. But Nhibernate does it for you. Read [this](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/14/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency.aspx)

Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control#Why_is_concurrency_control_needed.3F) for concurrency concept details